Change Color of Icon with R (!) magick
Goal
I have a couple of icons (technically sRGB but mostly black-ish or white-ish with a transparent background). I want to change the color to darkblue (say).
So each icon consist of a transparent background and a black-ish or white-ish foreground and I want to change this color to a color of my choice.
My attempt
Input Pic

N.B. I am using this pic as it ships with magick (which makes the example easier to reproduce) even if it does not resemble my real cases. Let's assume the white bar represents the background and the black area is my foreground.
Code
library(magick)
pic <- image_read(file.path(system.file(package = "magick"), 
                            "images", "shape_rectangle.gif"))

## find dark spot and use `image_fill`

pixels <- pic |>
  image_data() |>
  as.integer()

(idx <- which(pixels[, , 3] == max(pixels[, , 3]), arr.ind = TRUE)[1, ])
# row col 
#  49  25 

image_fill(pic, "darkblue", "+49+25")

Result

Problem
While this approach works in this simple case, I am not happy with this "solution" for my real icons. The logos can consist of several "areas" and while I could fill all dark spots, this seems to be first of all a total overkill and I assume that there is a function more suitable for this task rather than flood filling the area.
In principle I want to do exactly the same in R as has been done on command line here: How to colorize a black-transparent PNG icon with ImageMagick
Thus, I think that my idea with identifying dark spots and flood-filling is not the correct way of solving this issue and I am very happy to learn which magick functions are more appropriate for the task at hand.
Example Logo

This is a real example of my logos. You can see that there is a disconnected lid and the approach chosen would fail to color each area.

You are rather looking for a procedure of identifying all pixels associated with a certain colour, say red, and change those pixels found to a different colour? I.e. you are not looking for a procedure where the colour of some area (or shape) like the background is changed? (+1)

Actually, I just want to change the foreground color. That is everything which is not transparent (black in the example of the trash bin) should change to e.g. blue.

My attempt with identifying the "dark" pixels was just one idea I had, but already while developping this idea I felt it is a bad idea. So any solution which allows me to change the foreground color to a color of my choice will do.

After some more research, I found a rather elegant solution:

Extract the alpha channel (aka the background)
Negate it (i.e. getting the foreground) -> we get a mask
Make a blank image with the corresponding dimensions and color it with the target color.
Compose a picture with the colored background and the mask using CopyOpacity as operator, which (as far as I understood) copies the opacity which sets the opacity of the background to 0 and just keeps the foreground et voilà

change_icon_color <- function(pic, new_color) {
  dims <- pic %>% 
    image_info()
  mask <- pic %>% 
    image_channel("alpha") %>% 
    image_negate()
  image_blank(dims$width, dims$height, new_color) %>% 
    image_composite(mask, operator = "CopyOpacity")
}

## N.B. in this toy example we need to explicitly set the transparency
change_icon_color(pic %>% image_transparent("white"), "forestgreen")



Nice. I would be interested in seeing a more general solution: (1) identification of all pixels associated with a certain colour (by threshold, margin, range?), (2) changing those to a colour or colour gradient, if possible, of choice. Did you spot something directing in this direction while you researched? Anyway (+1).

This is unfortunately far beyond my capabilities. But I think the general idea of extracting a certain channel and using a composite can be generalized. Maybe we need some conversion of the layer to increase contrast between wanted and unwanted pixels, but this could be a potential route.
